# Representing relationships/hierarchy within an otherwise flat table view

Tags: tables, lists, data-tables, hierarchy, relationship

I have a standard table view which is used in a number of places in an online cloud portal. It's used to list servers, products, firewalls and more.

As I begin to build views for the firewall listing specifically, I've realised there's a slight difference in relationships here. With firewalls in particular, I need to be able to not only list them but also indicate that certain pairs in the list are linked. Specifically, I need to be able to represent a Master/Slave relationship.

I have re-ordered the list so that these pairs always appear next to each other and have also included a text column which says Master/Slave. But I can't seem to find a good way to represent these relationships more clearly without breaking the portal's UX consistency and doing something crazy like indenting certain rows.

[image: example table]

Answer (score 4):

I had two ideas while reading your problem.

First was showing a hierachy by using a tree view
[image: hierachy_in_list]

Second, a chain icon to show linking of elements (relationship)
[image: relationship_in_list]

Comment: First idea is a more accurate solution

Comment: I don't know if it is the case, but if there where several different relationships between. different firewalls the second option wouldn't really work. Treeview will definitely be better

Answer (score 2):

My colleague had a similar case recently. We decided to show the parents in the table with the expandable children lists.

Here're two types of showing this expand/collapse view: +/- and down/up pointing chevron

[image: Here're two types of showing this expand/collapse view: +/- and down/up pointing chevron]

Answer (score 2):

Your last example seems to be more common and used with hierarchical grids, as also shown on the [Shield UI examples](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/hierarchy).

Comment: Should this have been a comment to @rhauger?